# Do Access points use softMAC or hardMAC?

Tags: wifi, drivers

I am trying to understand the working of wireless in linux. I started with wpa_supplicant, hostapd applications with the help of their documentation and source code.Understood the flow and basic functionalities of :

1. wpa_supplicant,nl80211(driver interface)
2. libnl library(socket communication between user space and kernel using netlink protocol)
3. cfg80211(kernel interface used for communicating with the driver from userspace with the help of nl80211 implementation in user space),mac80211(software media access control layer)
4. driver(loadable driver ex:ath6kl - atheros driver).

I understood the above software flow and in my exploration I came to know that for providing freedom for developers MAC layer is implemented in software(popular implementation mac80211).

Is this true in all the cases ? If so what are pros and cons of softMAC and hardMAC ? Do cfg80211 interface in kernel directly communicates with the driver ? who and how communication with mac80211 happens ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My undestanding of the topic is: The advantage of a HardMAC device is basically that the MAC features and requirements of the underlying protocol are implemented on the device and are only accessible through an API, for example: AT Commands (what the specifications call the primitives). And yes, this is done internally by the device with software, so you will see HardMAC devices have a processor in combination with a radio transceiver. The main advantage is that the MAC processing is done on the HardMAC device and the disadvantage is that it is not flexible for custom applications, because you do not have direct access to the radio.

SoftMAC devices are radio transceivers that comply with the PHY and have some MAC features (commonly AutoAck, CRC checks, auto encrypt, destination checks, etc), so the user has to read all frame types and answer according to the specification (if he wants to).

I am not sure about cfg80211, but with some reading it seems to me that it is the API through witch user space programs can configure the radio. The cfg80211 API communicates with the driver normally via mac80211, but can also talk directly to the driver.